# Combine rows as the summation of column

Tags: sql, oracle

I currently have a table left joined by another table through a non-unique ID, however I am using a where clause to filter out the rows I want to see. Now I get two rows that give me valuable information separately, however I would only like the sum of the two rows to appear on my report.

```
select table1.a, table2.b
from table1 "a" left join table2 "b" 
on nonuniqueid1=nonuniqueid2
where.....
```

displays

```
A:011   100     
A:011   250
```

but I want

```
A:011   350
```

Comment: Please show the actual query, complete with a column list and the `WHERE` clause. Your current one does not match the output that you are showing.

Comment: What set of columns identify the rows that should be combined?  Do you only want to combine rows, for example, if columns 1-4 and 6 match?

Comment: @JustinCave all the other columns will be the same, so I want to combine rows if all other columns match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want a `group by` clause.

```
select table1.a, sum(table2.b) total_b
  from table1 
       left join table2  
         on nonuniqueid1=nonuniqueid2
 where.....
 group by table1.a
```

Comment: I tried that, I get 'Not a Group By Expression' error message

Comment: @Kevin - Does your actual query just have two columns?  The query you posted in your question wouldn't compile (you assign aliases `"a"` and `"b"` for example but then use `table1` and `table2` in your `select` list) so I cleaned it up in posting my answer.  If you have additional columns that you don't want to aggregate, you'd need to add those to the `group by` clause.